# Delete a specific row from a joined table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inner-join, delete-row

```
SELECT * 
FROM hotel_list h
INNER JOIN tariff_chart t ON h.hotel_id = t.hotel_id
WHERE t.hotel_id = "t16"
```

I want to delete this resultant row in my sql, what will be the code?

That is i want to delete all the data from `hotel_list` table and `tariff_chart` table, where `hotel_id="t16"`

Answer (score 0):

> That is i want to delete all the data from hotel_list table and
>   tariff_chart table, where hotel_id="t16"

First, I see no reason why to use a `join` here.

You should apply the [`ON DELETE CASCADE`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620086/CASCADE-in-SQL-Server-with-example) option on the `hotel_id` Primary-Key at the `hotel_list` table in order to delete all "child" rows (Foreign-Keys), like the one in the `tariff_chart` table.

If you specify this option, when you delete a row in the parent table, the database server also deletes any rows associated with that row (foreign keys) in a child table. The advantage of the ON DELETE CASCADE option is that it allows you to reduce the quantity of SQL statements needed to perform delete actions.

And then just do it like that:

```
DELETE FROM hotel_list WHERE HOTEL_ID = "T16";
```

Answer (score 0):

`DELETE FROM hotel_list h, tariff_chart t WHERE h.hotel_id = t.hotel_id AND t.hotel_id = "t16"`

You can check the exact syntax for multi table delete on the mysql reference site - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Answer (score 0):

While creating your tables in `phpMyAdmin`. you should create relations with both of these tables and in set `On Delete Cascade` for the `Foreign Key`.

In relation view of `tariff_chart` make `On Delete Cascade` for `hotel_id` field

So when ever you will delete a record in  Parent table it will automatically delete all child record in child table

So while running the query

```
DELETE FROM hotel_list WHERE HOTEL_ID = "T16";
```

will delete all child records from `tariff_chart` table

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE hotel_list
FROM hotel_list h
INNER JOIN tariff_chart t ON h.hotel_id = t.hotel_id
WHERE t.hotel_id = "t16"
```